# Sending specific PFUsers images from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, file, parse-platform

I want to be able to send specific users different photos directly from Parse.  What is the best way to go about this?

I already have a User Login & Registration completely set up. I also have a UIViewController filed as "Concepts" and a PFImageView filed as "Progress".

The class name is "UserPhoto" I have a file column named "imageFile" and a Pointer<_User> column named "user". I am going to be storing the "imageFile" names under "Image.jpg"

I feel like I am way off track from any type of progress so any any help would be greatly appreciated.  As of right now, with two weeks of research on achieving this, I have yet to find a solution that works for me.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Progress.h"

@interface Concepts : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Progress *image1;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "Concepts.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Progress.h"

@interface Concepts ()

@end

@implementation Concepts
@synthesize image1;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];

    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Retrieved data");

        if (!error) {
            PFFile *image1 = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];


        }
    }];
    }
```

PFImageView.h

```
#import "Progress.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Concepts.h"


@interface Progress : PFImageView

@end
```

PFImageView.m

```
#import "Progress.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Concepts.h"

@implementation Progress

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get image for any specific user, you need to put where clause in query, Parse has provided plenty of options:

[image]

Then simply get result by:

```
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    //result

   }];
```

Comment: thank you! what would I put in the  (NSString *) & (NSArray *)? 
@shrejas

Comment: It depends on your requirement, on basis of what you are quering table, for example suppose there is a Fruit table and you need fruits who are either red or yellow in color, in that case NSString will contain column name "fruit_color" and value of array will be @[ @"red", @"yellow"]

Comment: How do I declare the NSString, which in my case is "imageFile"? In addition to the information you've provided, the code I posted up top is all I currently have.